# Using Class, Methods to define variables

Tags: python, list, call

I have a number of chemicals with corresponding data held within a database, how do I go about returning a specific chemical, and its data, via its formula, eg o2.

```
class SourceNotDefinedException(Exception):
def __init__(self, message):
    super(SourceNotDefinedException, self).__init__(message)

class tvorechoObject(object):
"""The class stores a pair of objects, "tv" objects, and "echo" objects. They are accessed
simply by doing .tv, or .echo. If it does not exist, it will fall back to the other variable.
If neither are present, it returns None."""
def __init__(self, echo=None, tv=None):
    self.tv = tv
    self.echo = echo

def __repr__(self):
    return str({"echo": self.echo, "tv": self.tv}) # Returns the respective strings

def __getattribute__(self, item):
    """Altered __getattribute__() function to return the alternative of .echo / .tv if the requested
    attribute is None."""

    if item in ["echo", "tv"]:    
        if object.__getattribute__(self,"echo") is None: # Echo data not present
            return object.__getattribute__(self,"tv") # Select TV data
        elif object.__getattribute__(self,"tv") is None: # TV data not present
            return object.__getattribute__(self,"echo") # Select Echo data
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self,item) # Return all data

    else:
        return object.__getattribute__(self,item) # Return all data


class Chemical(object):
    def __init__(self, inputLine, sourceType=None):
        self.chemicalName = TVorEchoObject()    
        self.mass = TVorEchoObject()
        self.charge = TVorEchoObject()


        self.readIn(inputLine, sourceType=sourceType)

def readIn(self, inputLine, sourceType=None):

    if sourceType.lower() == "echo": # Parsed chemical line for Echo format 


        chemicalName            = inputLine.split(":")[0].strip()
        mass               = inputLine.split(":")[1].split(";")[0].strip()
        charge                 = inputLine.split(";")[1].split("]")[0].strip()


        # Store the objects
        self.chemicalName.echo = chemicalName
        self.mass.echo = mass
        self.charge.echo = charge


    elif sourceType.lower() == "tv": # Parsed chemical line for TV format


        chemicalName          = inputLine.split(":")[0].strip()
        charge               = inputLine.split(":")[1].split(";")[0].strip()
        mass                 = inputLine.split(";")[1].split("&")[0].strip()


        # Store the objects
        self.chemicalName.tv = chemicalName
        self.charge.tv = charge
        self.mass.tv  = molecularWeight

    else:
        raise SourceNotDefinedException(sourceType + " is not a valid `sourceType`") # Otherwise print 


def toDict(self, priority="echo"):
    """Returns a dictionary of all the variables, in the form {"mass":<>, "charge":<>, ...}.
    Design used is to be passed into the Echo and TV style line format statements."""
    if priority in ["echo", "tv"]:
    # Creating the dictionary by a large, to avoid repeated text
        return dict([(attributeName, self.__getattribute__(attributeName).__getattribute__(priority))
            for attributeName in ["chemicalName", "mass", "charge"]])
    else:
        raise SourceNotDefinedException("{0} source type not recognised.".format(priority)) # Otherwise print






from ParseClasses import Chemical
allChemical = []
chemicalFiles = ("/home/temp.txt")


for fileName in chemicalFiles:
    with open(fileName) as sourceFile:
        for line in sourceFile:
        allChemical.append(Chemical(line, sourceType=sourceType))

for chemical in allChemical:
    print chemical.chemicalName #Prints all chemicals and their data in list format

for chemical in allChemical(["o2"]):
    print chemical.chemicalName
```

outputs the following error which I have tried to remedy with no luck;
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Looks like `allChemicals` is a `list` - did you mean `for chemical in allChemicals[2]:` or even `for chemical in allChemicals:`? You need to give us more details about your data structure, otherwise we can only guess. See also this post about how to write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It looks like `allChemicals` is supposed to be a list of objects of some kind. You need to include its definition here and the object definition for us to be able to tell you how to use them.

Comment: Is `allChemicals` a typo? If so, when you do this: `allChemical = []` you are making an empty list with the name allChemical. Then when you do: `allChemicals(["o2"])` you are *calling* the list (that's what the parentheses are doing) with an argument. You can't call a list object that way. You are not using the `allChemical` object correctly. This is what is causing the error. Hard to say how to fix it without more information.

Comment: What is it that you are expecting `allChemical(["o2"])` to return? Have you tried something like this...? `print(allChemical["o2"])`? But that will only work of `allChemical` is a dictionary object, not a list.

Comment: I want it to print all species and corresponding data related to o2, this would include o2-, o2+ etc. print(allSpecies["o2"]) results in TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function:

```
def chemByString(chemName,chemicals,priority="echo"):
    for chemical in chemicals:
        chemDict = chemical.toDict(priority)
        if chemDict["chemicalName"] == chemName
            return chemical
    return None
```

This function is using the `toDict()` method found in the `Chemical` class. The code you pasted from the `Chemical` class explains that this method returns a dictionary from the chemical object:

```
def toDict(self, priority="echo"):
    """Returns a dictionary of all the variables, in the form {"mass":<>, "charge":<>, ...}.
    Design used is to be passed into the Echo and TV style line format statements."""
    if priority in ["echo", "tv"]:
    # Creating the dictionary by a large, to avoid repeated text
        return dict([(attributeName, self.__getattribute__(attributeName).__getattribute__(priority))
            for attributeName in ["chemicalName", "mass", "charge"]])
    else:
        raise SourceNotDefinedException("{0} source type not recognised.".format(priority)) # Otherwise print
```

This dictionary looks like this:

```
"chemicalName" : <the chemical name>
"mass" :         <the mass>
"charge" :       <the charge>
```

What the function I created above does is iterate through all of the chemicals in the list, finds the first one with a name equal to "o2", and returns that chemical. Here's how to use it:

```
chemByString("o2",allChemicals).chemicalName
```

If the above does not work, may want to try using the alternative priority ("tv"), though I'm unsure if this will have any effect:

```
chemByString("o2",allChemicals,"tv").chemicalName
```

If the chemical isn't found, the function returns `None`:

```
chemByString("myPretendChemical",allChemicals).chemicalName
```

Comment: thank you so much. This helps significantly, I am still having problems returning all dictionary objects relating to all the data for O2, ie, mass and charge.

Comment: The code still outputs data from both echo and tv though, despite priority being defined?

Comment: Hmmm... yeah I'm not certain how that works. The code is a little confusing and I haven't tried to run it myself yet. I'll try to remember to look at it some more later when I have time. Feel free to remind me in a day or two if you're still having problems.

Comment: Also: it might be helpful to also include a few lines from a sample input file.

Comment: the following code  results in the data  required from the specific source, thanks for your help;
str(chemByString('O2', allChemicals,priority="echo").chemicalName)  + str(" {chemicalName:<5s} {charge:<20s}".format(**chemByString('O2', allChemicals,priority="echo").toDict()))

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the two lines

```
for chemical in allChemical(["o2"]):
    print chemical.chemicalName
```

`allChemical` is a list, and you can't just do `a_list()`. It looks like you're trying to find either `['o2']` or just `'o2'` in a list. To do that, you can get the index of the item and then get that index from the list.

```
allChemical[allChemical.index("o2")]
```

Comment: The issue is bigger than this, though. The objects in the `list` don't seem to be strings, so `index("o2")` probably won't find them. Unless they are subclassed from `str` or something.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: See my new answer. Leaving this one here since it might still be helpful info.

In python, a list object is a structure holding other objects with an index for each object it contains. Like this:

```
Index    Object
0        "hello"
1        "world"
2        "spam"
```

If you want to get to one of those objects, you have to know its index:

```
objList[0] #returns "hello" string object
```

If you don't know the index, you can find it using the `index` method:

```
objList.index("hello") #returns 0
```

Then you can get the object out of the list using the found index:

```
objList[objList.index("hello")]
```

However this is kind of silly, since you can just do:

```
"hello"
```

Which in this case will produce the same result.

Your `allChemical` object is a list. It looks like the line `chemicalFiles = ("/home/temp.txt")` is filling your list with some type of object. In order to answer your question, you have to provide more information about the objects which the list contains. I assume that information is in the `ParseClasses` module you are using.

If you can provide more information about the `Chemical` object you are importing, that may go a long way to helping solve your problem.

IF the objects contained in your list are subclassed from `str`, this MAY work:

```
allChemical[allChemical.index("o2")].chemicalName
```

`"02"` is a `str` object, so `index` is going to look for a `str` object (or an object subclassed from `str`) in your list to find its index. However, if the object isn't a string, it will not find it.

As a learning exercise, try this:

```
class Chemical(str):
'''A class which is a subclass of string but has additional attributes such as chemicalName'''
    def __init__(self,chemicalName):
        self.chemicalName = chemicalName

someChemicals = [Chemical('o2'),Chemical('n2'),Chemical('h2')]

for chemical in someChemicals: print(chemical.chemicalName) 
#prints all the chemical names
print(someChemicals[0].chemicalName) 
#prints "o2"; notice you have to know the index ahead of time
print(someChemicals[someChemicals.index("o2")].chemicalName) 
#prints "o2" again; this time index found it for you, but
#you already knew the object ahead of time anyway, sot it's a little silly
```

This works because index is able to find what you are looking for. If it isn't a string it can't find it, and if you don't know what index 'o2' is at, if you want to get to a specific chemical in your list of chemicals you're going to have to learn more about those objects.